# How can i align two widgets to the extreme right and one to the left in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

Hey guys, please how can I align widgets just like it is in this image. I want to align the years to the left and the data numbers to the extreme right. However, I want to align the arrow svg so it rests on the data numbers. If you notice in the image, the arrow images shifts according to how large or small the data numbers is and the year texts in the extreme left remains in one position. So basically the arrow icon is resting on the data numbers to the right and adjusts it self accordingly. How can I do this in flutter

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet for row item?

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a `Row` and use `mainAxisAlignment` to specify the alignment:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    FirstWidget(),
    SecondWidget(),
  ],
)
```

Comment: You put in two widgets in your answer. So how can I align it when there are three widgets. The year to the left, the icon and the data numbers to the right

Comment: You have two options. Either you can wrap multiple widgets in the second widget (eg. make it a Row aswell). Or you can remove the mainAxisAlignment and use the Spacer widget instead ([link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)). In that case use `children:[First(),Spacer(),Second(),Third()]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Row widget and inside you have to declare four children widget....

First widget is year text and second icon upper arrow..you can use SizedBox widget to mention distance between these two widgets...

SizedBox(width: 20)

Then third text widget and fourth icon forward.....

You can get the output as per your image...

Better wrap your text widget with container with fixed width to align arrows straight

Answer (score 0):

According to ui, we can say for year we can consume 60% of width and rest 40% is used for icons and number-data.

We can use nested for this. It will be like.

```dart
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Flexible(
      flex: 6,
      child: Text("Year ${index * 2 + index * 13}"),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 4,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
              Text("${Random().nextInt(2222 ^ 8)}"),
            ],
          ),
          const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

You can handle detraction based on your need

[image]

Comment: Can you help in answering my previous question about copying text from a button

Comment: Can you include the question link